# stsadm.exe crashes on all commands

Tags: stsadm, error, 2007

All of a sudden, stsadm has stopped working, crashing on all commands it is run with (even -help!)

e.g.

```
> stsadm.exe -help
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path
   at System.IO.DirectoryInfo..ctor(String path)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.EnsureExtendedOperationMap()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.EnsureFullOperationMap()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.LookupOperationName(String strOperation)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.StsAdmin.SPStsAdmin.Main(String[] args)
```

I'm baffled as to why.  The only significant thing to change on the server between yesterday and today was the installation of the Citrix Web Interface for SharePoint webparts.

**UPDATE**: I also receive the following error when starting Central Administration from the Start Menu (Start -> Microsoft Office Server -> SharePoint 3.0 Central Administration)

> A failure occurred when accessing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\12.0\WSS registry key.  Repair this product by selecting it from the Add/Remove Programs menu.

If I access Central Administration via a browser and typing in the URL (e.g. http://intranet:8080), it works fine.

**MORE UPDATE:** I dug into stsadm a bit by disassembling with .NET Reflector.  Turns out the line it is bailing on is:

```
FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("config")).GetFiles("stsadmcommands.*.xml");
```

in the `EnsureExtendedOperationMap()` method.

The reason being, I believe, because `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("config")` is returning null.  I set up a test console app and sure enough, `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("config")` returns null.  So something is obviously severely hosed somewhere.

I noticed when running the test console app that I get the following output:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

which doesn't sound good.  So I ask Visual Studio to break on all exceptions, even handled ones, and the exception is as follows:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'onetnative.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Note: I've started a [separate question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4202/unable-to-load-onetnative-dll-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) regarding this onetnative.dll problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can trace it back, this was caused by an installation of the wrong version of Microsoft J#.

J# is a pre-requisite of the Citrix Web Interface for SharePoint webparts.  I installed the 32bit version mistakenly, then uninstalled and installed the 64bit version.  I have a hunch (based on a good bit of testing, but not 100% verified) that this caused .NET/CLR applications to start looking in the 32bit node of the registry rather than 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

Has UAC been enabled and you are not running your command prompt as an Administrator perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, but no -- UAC is disabled, and I'm running as administrator.