# Unable to load 'onetnative.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: 2007, error, sputility

This question arises as a result of [this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4149/stsadm-exe-crashes-on-all-commands), but I thought I would split it out into its own.

Anything using `SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath()` is returning null, e.g.

```
SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath("config")
SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(string.Empty)
```

both return null.  If I make those calls in a little console app and debug it in VS2008, it appears to execute fine with no exceptions (albeit with null returned from the method.)  However I notice a message in the output window:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

So if I get Visual Studio to break on all exceptions, even handled ones, the exception is as follows:

> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'onetnative.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I've checked and onetnative.dll does exist in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can trace it back, this was caused by an installation of the wrong version of Microsoft J#.

J# is a pre-requisite of the Citrix Web Interface for SharePoint webparts.  I installed the 32bit version mistakenly, then uninstalled and installed the 64bit version.  I have a hunch (based on a good bit of testing, but not 100% verified) that this caused .NET/CLR applications to start looking in the 32bit node of the registry rather than 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would try copying the onetnative.dll to the same place as your console app and see if it makes a difference