# Is it safe to 'repair' MOSS 2007 via the Control Panel?

Tags: 2007, windows-server

Something has gone wrong with my SharePoint install (see [stsadm.exe crashes on all commands](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4149/stsadm-exe-crashes-on-all-commands)), and with the errors involving registry keys and dlls not being found, I'm thinking something pretty major has happened.  Short of doing a reinstall, I'm wondering whether a 'Repair' of MOSS 2007 via Control Panel -> Programs might do any good.

(Although I've a feeling the problems are more at the WSS level, but I don't see that in the Programs list...)

I'm on Windows 2008.

Does 'Repairing' MOSS 2007 do anything useful, and more important, might it 'repair' (i.e. delete) things I wouldn't want it to?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps running the Sharepoint Configuration Wizard can help you out also. It's a bit safer as the 'Repair' option I think.

Comment: Thanks... I tried that and got an error :/  I'm going to post it in a separate question.

Comment: Posted here: http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/4208/a-failure-occurred-when-accessing-the-hkey-local-machine-software-microsoft-share

Comment: Well, in that case it's probably best to do a 'Repair' from the Control Panel, as the logline suggests in the other question.
Don't know how it will affect your current install though.